# How put checkboxs into Combobox in vaadin

Tags: jquery-ui, checkbox, combobox, vaadin

I am currently developing app using Vaadin. and my working scenario is to put numbers of chcekboxs into combobox. this scenario work very nice with JQuery UI. unfortunately I couldn’t find any way to make it works on vaadin..

So please kindly give me some Idea or resources

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Can you put any image or code?

Comment: what is your ultimate goal here?  a searchable multiselect? please also add what you have tried so far?

Comment: The idea similar to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/igalst/rjwosg11/

Select2 with checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to add checkbox inside ComboBox. If you need to work with Javascript, You can use GWT Widget or JavaScript components, as well as component and UI extensions.

See My code below it is very simple vaadin javascript component:

```
@JavaScript({ "theme://javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js", 
          "theme://javascript/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"})
@StyleSheet("theme://javascript/chosen/chosen.css")
public clas VChosenComponent extends VerticalLayout {

    private String id;
    public List<String> values;
    public List<String> selectedValues;

    private String onChangeDynamicFunction;  // Use to passing javascript value to java code

    public VChosenComponent(List<Integer> values) {
       this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public void attach() {
        super.attach();
        try {
            id = "chosen-" + getConnectorId();
            onChangeDynamicFunction = VChosenComponent.class.getCanonicalName() + getConnectorId();

            StringBuffer  divHTML = new StringBuffer();
            divHTML.append("<");
            divHTML.append("select data-placeholder=\"Choose a Country...\" style=\"width:350px;\" tabindex=\"1\"> ");
            divHTML.append("    <option value=\"\"></option> ");
            for(String value : values) {
              divHTML.append("  <option value=\"" + value + "\">" + value + "</option> ");
            }
            divHTML.append("</select>");

            Label html = new Label(divHTML.toString(), ContentMode.HTML);
            html.setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            html.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

            removeAllComponents();
            addComponent(html);

            StringBuffer  jsScript = new StringBuffer();
            jsScript.append("function() {");
            jsScript.append("   $('#" + id + "').chosen({no_results_text: \"Oops, nothing found!\"});");
            jsScript.append("   $('#" + id + "').chosen().change(function(){ ");
            jsScript.append("       " + dynamicFunction + "($(this).val());");
            jsScript.append("   });");
            jsScript.append("}");

            JavaScript javascript = JavaScript.getCurrent(); 
            javascript.addFunction(dynamicFunction, new JavaScriptFunction() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3013252366773470787L;
                    @Override
                    public void call(JsonArray arguments) {
                        String value = arguments.getString(0);

                // Corrrect here for your real work
                selectedValue.add(value);
            }
           });

                javascript.execute("setTimeout(" + jsScript.toString() + ", 1)");

        } catch (Throwable t) {
                 setVisible(false);
        }
    }

  public List<String> getSelectedValues() {
    return this.selectedValue;
  }
}
```

Hope this could help you :)

Comment: Ok!! this solution is good. with javascript we can create richer vaadin component. Thanks

Comment: Vaadin widget and GWT widget are difficult to implement. As the JavaScript integration does not involve GWT programming, no widget set compilation is needed. If you want to know more please read this link :  [Vaadin-GWT-Javascript](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you try to develop a multi-select `ComboBox`. Unfortunately it's not possible to add any components like `CheckBox`es inside a `ComboBox`.

Maybe you could use components like `Grid` or `Table` if you need multi selection.